# Levene test in R

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, levenes-test

I tested for equality of variance between two groups in R

`Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = mean)
      Df F value Pr(>F)
group  1  0.5353 0.4679
      49`

I am assuming the default confidence interval is 95%, based on a p-value of 0.47, it means that I cannot reject the null hypothesis that the variances are not equal. The data is also not normally distributed, so my question is:

To test for significant differences between the means, should I be using Wilcoxon test or perhaps Welch two sample t-test on log transformed data?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on *how* your data differ from appearing Normal.

Comment: I used qqplots, and histograms and I could not make a strong argument for a normal distribution. But then again my sample size is small (<30) so I think it's safe to use Mann Whitney?

Comment: At the *5% level*, the null hypothesis of *equal* variances can't be rejected. Your wording needs to be improved.

Comment: "I am assuming the default confidence interval is 95%…" There is no confidence interval in the output you provide.